# replace default image with contact photo when image doesn't exist in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am trying to fetch contact data from phonegap for android , here I am trying to fetch the contact image and trying to replace it with the default image if the actual contact photo doesnt exist.

now in phonegap when we try to access photo it returns the url even if the photo doesn't exist. so what I am trying here to create `Image`  object and assigning the photo url fetched from phonegap if the image doesnt exist , `Image` object will raise `onerror` exception and inside that I am changing its `src` attribute to default image.

but now the problem is `onerror` functions fires late  I mean after the data loads so `src` attribute is not getting changed. so can any one tell me how do I mange `onerror`

```
   if(contacts[i].photos){  
                        for(k =0 ;k < contacts[i].photos.length;k++){



                            var imgVal = new Image();
                            imgVal.onerror = function(){


                          this.src= 'resources/images/default_usr.png';
                          this.error = null;

                                contactData.setContactImage(this.outerHTML);
                                console.log("2");
                            }
                            imgVal.width="45";
                            imgVal.height="45";
                            imgVal.src = contacts[i].photos[k].value;

                            contactData.setContactImage(imgVal.src);


                            console.log("1");       

                        }//end for contact photo
                    }// end if contact photo
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a default background image, which is the contact photo.
than let it load the photo in it, if the real photo exist it will load in it.

the html code is:

```
<img src="Path/to/image" id="img"/>
```

the css will be something like this:

```
#img{background: url(path/to/default/image) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; backgorund-size:100% 100%; height:45px; width:45px; display:block;}
```

Comment: i am adding the `img` tag dynamically

Comment: than you should use "live" function in jquery

Comment: m using snecha touch not jquery

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how you create contactData and I haven't done this myself, but here are a couple of considerations from reading your code, assuming that currently your debug console shows

```
1
2
```

while no image is assigned.

- In the main loop, you invoke 
  contactData.setContactImage(**imgVal.src**); with the **image src** property as a parameter (the image url); In the error loop, you assign **this.src** which hopefully is the same imgVal object and then pass the object's **outerHTML** property to the setContactImage. This is very different, for consistency you should pass this.src as an argument and I couldn't find the official docs, but from a few samples I found the parameter should be the full Image object.  Whichever the parameter type, it needs to be consistent across the two calls.
- to make your life easier, javascript uses closures i.e. imgVal is still available in the onerror event so you could use imgVal instead of this;
- try to console.log(imgVal) in both the main loop and the error declaration (or the exact parameter you are invoking the function setContactData with); this should clear things up;
- onerror cannot be too late; you are invoking a method that will start its own execution. It may be forbidden to invoke it in an onerror clause (because you risk an infinite onerror loop) - this is just a hypothesis though, I never tried; but you might still work around this creating a new Image object in the onerror function.