# How do you specify URLs for Contact.photos?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, contacts, android-contacts, cordova-plugins

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#contact

Where can I put the image file (eg can I have it on S3, or shipped with the app in the resources), and what is the correct format for the `URL`?

```
var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
contact.photos = [new ContactField('url', URL, true)];
contact.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your answer....Sir.

```
var photos = [];

var ImgUrl="images/Thomas.jpg";

photos[0] = new ContactField('url', ImgUrl,true);
contact.photos = photos;
```

Comment: Thanks, so "images/Thomas.jpg" is shipped with your app resources? What about a dynamic image that you have a HTTP url for?

Comment: This is the answer for your answer:- http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/cordova-formerly-phonegap

Comment: That only shows `contact.urls`. I meant adding to `contact.photos` based on an image downloaded from a url.

Comment: Check this link..it will help:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469365/replace-default-image-with-contact-photo-when-image-doesnt-exist-in-phonegap